# Bevel after Boolean

Tags: bevel

I would like the edges to be rounded a bit. I tought this could be done with a Bevel modifier, but nothing seems to happen.
Is there a way to round the edges of the hexagons?
[image]
[image]

Disabeling the Clamp options makes a mess of the mesh.
[image]

The hexagons are not toughing each other.
[image]

UPDATE
the solution works! It's a bit of work to add more mesh so it matches the original shape of the feet tho.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bevel because you have the *Clamp Overlap* of the *Bevel* modifier enabled, but you can't disable it otherwise you'll have bad topology.

In my opinion you should rethink your topology, as you already have your hexagons (your boolean object), make them stick to the foot with the help of a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, then create faces between the hexagons like that (image below). When you're good, delete the hexagons and give thickness with a *Solidify* modifier or with an *Extrude Faces Along Normals* (and retopologize the rest of the object with a clean topology).

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate the last steps. How now do I get round edges?

Comment: Once you have a good toplogy like the one I show, you simply bevel the edges?

Comment: aa yes. We abandon the original shape of the feet and make a new object with the hexagons. But then I will lose the exact shape of the feet...

Comment: You need to retopologize a low-poly with the Snap tool, use the current foot as your high-poly